# How to average values in one column of a csv if the values in another column are not changing?

Tags: python, csv

EDIT:  See end of my post for working code, obtained from zeekay [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9399376/1224320).

I have a CSV file with two columns (voltage and current).  Because the voltage is recorded to many significant digits and the current only has 2, there are many identical current values as the value of the voltage changes.  This isn't important to the programming but I'm just explaining how the data is physically obtained.  I want to perform the following action:

For as long as the value of the second column (current) does not change, collect the values of the first column (voltage) into a list and average them.  Then write a row into a new CSV file which is this averaged value of the voltage in the first column and the constant current value which did not change in the second column.  In other words, if there are 20 rows for which the current did not change (say it is 6 uA), the 20 corresponding voltage values are averaged (say this average comes out to be 600 mV) and a row is generated in a new csv file which reads ('0.6','0.000006').  Then I want to continue iterating through the csv which is being read, repeating the above procedure for each set of fixed currents.

I've got the following code so far, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track:

```
import sys, csv
with open('filetowriteto.csv','w') as avg:
    loadeddata = open('filetoreadfrom.csv','r')
    writer=csv.writer(avg)
    readloaded=csv.reader(loadeddata)
    listloaded=list(readloaded)
    oldcurrent=listloaded[0][1]
    for row in readloaded:
        newcurrent = row[1]
        biaslist = []
        if newcurrent == oldcurrent:
            biaslist.append(row[0])
        else :
            biasavg = float(sum(biaslist))/len(biaslist)
            writer.writerow([biasavg,newcurrent])
            newcurrent = row[1]
```

and then I'm not sure where to go.

Edit:  It seems that zeekay is on the right track for what I want to do.  I'm trying to implement his itertools.groupby() method but I'm currently getting a blank file generated.  Here's my new code so far:

```
import sys, csv, itertools
with open('VI_avg(12).csv','w') as avg: # this is the file which gets written
    loadeddata = open('VI(12).csv','r') # this is the file which is read
    writer=csv.writer(avg)
    readloaded=csv.reader(loadeddata)
    listloaded=list(readloaded)
    oldcurrent=listloaded[0][1] # looks like this is no longer required
    for current, row in itertools.groupby(readloaded, lambda x: x[1]):
        biaslist = [float(x[0]) for x in row]
        biasavg = float(sum(biaslist))/len(biaslist)
        # write it out
        writer.writerow(biasavg, current)
```

Suppose the CSV file being opened is something like this (shortened example):

0.595417,0.000065
0.595177,0.000065
0.594937,0.000065
0.594697,0.000065
0.594457,0.000065
0.594217,0.000065
0.593977,0.000065
0.593737,0.000065
0.593497,0.000064
0.593017,0.000064
0.592777,0.000064
0.592537,0.000064
0.592297,0.000064
0.587018,0.000064
0.586778,0.000064
0.586538,0.000063
0.586299,0.000063
0.586059,0.000063
0.585579,0.000063
0.585339,0.000063
0.585099,0.000063
0.584859,0.000063
0.584619,0.000063
0.584379,0.000063
0.584139,0.000063
0.583899,0.000063
0.583659,0.000063

Final update:  Here's the working version, obtained from [zeekay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9399376/1224320):

```
import csv
import itertools

with open('VI(12).csv') as input, open('VI_avg(12).csv','w') as output:
    reader = csv.reader(input)
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    for current, row in itertools.groupby(reader, lambda x: x[1]):
        biaslist = [float(x[0]) for x in row]
        biasavg = float(sum(biaslist))/len(biaslist)
        writer.writerow([biasavg, current])
```

Comment: I would actually suggest performing a regression on the current data, to gain extra decimal digits of precision, which while virtual will still be meaningful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group results as you read through the csv, which would simplify things a lot. Given your updated example:

```
import csv
import itertools

with open('VI(12).csv') as input, open('VI_avg(12).csv','w') as output:
    reader = csv.reader(input)
    writer = csv.writer(output)
    for current, row in itertools.groupby(reader, lambda x: x[1]):
        biaslist = [float(x[0]) for x in row]
        biasavg = float(sum(biaslist))/len(biaslist)
        writer.writerow([biasavg, current])
```

Comment: This looks simpler than what I had in mind, which is great.  I just picked up Python on Friday so it may take me a little while to sort out itertools.groupby but I will look into it right now!  Thanks!

Comment: I've added your code and the script does not return errors but the file which is generated is blank.

Comment: You might want to update your example to indicate this (and also include an example csv). I have no idea *how* you added it :)

Comment: Thanks for your patience and kindness!  I've updated my example and included a few dozen example lines of a csv file.

Comment: I updated my example to reflect what you want to do. Note that you need to pass `writer.writerow` the columns as a list, or tuple. I also demonstrate how to use a nested with statement, which is available in Python 2.7.

Comment: If you have any further issues, update your example as well as explain the error you run into.

Comment: That did it, thank you!  If I had enough reputation I would vote your suggestion up to the heavens.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas
voltage = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3]
current = [1.0, 1.0, 1.1, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3]
df = pandas.DataFrame({'voltage': voltage, 'current': current}) 
result = df.groupby('current').mean()

# Output
         voltage
current         
1.0      1.15   
1.1      1.30   
1.2      2.20   
1.3      2.20 

result.to_csv('grouped_data.csv')
```

Comment: This seems to group the non-consecutive currents of 1.3.  I would want the output currents to read off 1.0, 1.1, 1.3, 1.2, 1.3.

Comment: I think that it can be done adding another column that indicates current groups, but the solution provided by zeekay is more clear and doesn't require extra packages. It can be useful to take a look at pandas anyway if you are working with experimental data.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
curDict = {}
for row in loaded row:
  if row[1] not in curDict.keys(): # if not already there create key/value pair
    curDict[str(row[1])] = [row[0]]
  else: # already exists, add to key/value pair
    curDict[str(row[1])].append(row[0])

#You'll end up with:
# {'0.6': [599, 600, 601...], ...}


# write the rows
for k,v in curDict.values():
  avgValue = reduce(lambda a,b: a+b, v)/len(v) # calculate the avg of the voltages
  writer.writerow([k,avgValue])
```

Answer (score 0):

This version will do what you describe, but it will average *all* values with the same voltage, regardless of whether they are consecutive or not. Apologies if that's not what you want, but maybe it can help you along the way:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

def f(acc, row):
    acc[row[1]].append(float(row[0]))
    return acc

with open('out.csv', 'w') as out:
  writer = csv.writer(out)

  data = open('in.csv', 'r')
  r = csv.reader(data)

  reduced = reduce(f, r, defaultdict(list))
  for v, c in reduced.items():
      writer.writerow([v, sum(c)/len(c)])
```

Comment: User zeekay responded with an implementation of itertools.groupby() which did the trick.

Comment: That was a nice solution. I'll make sure to remember it.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way using some very small test data  (haven't included the csv stuff as you appear to have a handle on that):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

test_data = [       # Only 3 currents in testdata:
    (0.00030,5),    #   5 : Only one entry, total 0.00030 - so should give 0.00030 as the average
    (0.00012,6),    #   6 : Two entries,    total 0.00048 - so should give 0.00024 as the average
    (0.00036,6),
    (0.00001,7),    #   7 : Four entries,   total 0.00008 - so should give 0.00002 as the average
    (0.00001,7),
    (0.00001,7),
    (0.00007,7)]

currents = dict()

for row in test_data:
    if not row[1] in currents:
        matching_currents = list((each[0] for each in test_data if each[1] == row[1]))
        current_average = sum(matching_currents) / len(matching_currents)
        currents[row[1]] = current_average

print("There were {0} unique currents found:\n".format(len(currents)))
for current,bias in currents.items():
    print("Current: {0:2d}   ( Average: {1:1.5f} )".format(current,bias))
```